# In-app Purchase Subscription

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

1. If we implement auto renewable monthly subscription in-app purchase and after two month if there is no sufficient amount in my account is subscription is expired(cancel) or subscription will renew when sufficient amount is avilable?
2. Our application concept is like every user have to pay fees every month to use the application service so we have made consumable. Ex if  A user login in application and purchase subscription with X apple account after that A user logout from the application and login with B user now when B user try to subscribe with same apple account then its give prompt like you have already subscribe the application. Please suggest what we should do ?

**NOTE : Application is available in Android and IOS as well**

Answer (score 1):

1. Subscription will get cancelled and **Not** get renewed. Apple checks for available balance prior to the date of subscription. If there is no balance then subscription will be cancelled.
2. It is what it should happen and this should be handelled by the application itself. Apple can only tell you if a purchase is made from an Apple account. If in your application, user A purchases from apple account of X, and then he logs out from the app, sign's in from user B then userB will be said that already purchased, As purchase is being made from apple account of X.

But after that popup, apple would require the password. So user B cannot make that purchase with account X, he has to logout from settings and use his own apple account to make that purchase, as he/she cannot give the password of account X.

Hope this helps.
I also made a class for auto renewable subscription in github. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/SahebRoy92/SRSubscriptionModel) if you like.

## EDIT

Answer to your question--

1. A user shoudnt be able to have to account with the same apple account. If he wants to avail that content again with another account (user B with account X) and gives password, then again that amount will get deducted (only for consumable), if non consumable then they will get access without deduction and as per as subscription. A new subscription will be added to the queue, that will begin at the end of the current term.
   You have to handle this in your application side, or leave it upto the idiocity of the user.
2. Apple would return you that subscription was cancelled whn you run your application the next time. All you need to know if you want to show your content, doesnt matter if it was cancelled by user or due to unavailable balance. All u need to know if you want to show or not.

Comment: 1.Thanks for the information but problem is then X have 2 account in my application A & B after popup if B give the password  then problem is subscription is extended for A & B both.

Comment: 2. How can i came to know subscription has cancelled due to no balance and application is available in Android & Apple platform as well.

Comment: We came across the same kind of X-A-B problem, however for non-consumable in-Apps. Eventually, we went with leaving it "up to the idiocity of the user". All we did, though, was assigning username hash to `applicationUsername` `SKMutablePayment`'s property. As of Apple docs, this should somehow prevent X-A-B cases. The purchase restoration also should go with `restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername:` method.

Comment: @Saheb Roy regarding 2. Lets assume user A subscription cancelled from apple at  same time if A try to login from android application how android app know the user subscription has cancelled. Our application user can subscription from any platform(Android and IOS).

Comment: you need to maintain that in your application, either make user login from a single device at a time, dont allow multiple login from device..

Comment: @SahebRoy Roy Got it Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Dubinin Can you please explain more? didn't got your point perfectly.

Comment: @Ashish Thummar what I meant was, we didn't handle purchases on our side and totally relied on Apple with that. So, in case several users are trying to restore purchases from the same Apple ID, Apple should prevent this from happening somehow via comparing username hashes between a restore and original purchase.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin Okay Thanks.